# How to send date from parent Fragment to Child Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

I'm an Android novice.
As with the title, I want to convey some data from Parents Fragment to child Fragment.
But I'm stuck in it and very hard.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try saving your child Fragment as a variable in your parent Pragment. Then you are able to call public methods like in your case `childFragment.setDate(date)`.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer information from the parent fragment to the child create an interface

```
interface YourListner{
    void methodToPassData(Date date);
}
```

After which the child fragment should implement this interface
Then you can cast the fragment to the type of the interface and pass the date to it by calling the method.

```
ChildFragment fragment = new ChuldFragment();
//display fragment
YourListner fragmentListener = (YourListner)fragmentListener;
fragmentListener.methodToPassData(date);
```

You can also do this using the constructor in the child fragment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I don't know the answer just from what you said. Can you give me a more detailed example?!

Comment: I think it would be good to express it with a simple java class. Or I don't know exactly where that code belongs.